# Lattice for vertices?

Tags: modeling

I recently watched a gun modelling tutorial in 3ds max and the instructor often used a tool called "FFD modifier".

The way he used it was by selecting a few vertices/edges, click the ffd modifier and then he could transform only those vertices

[image]

Is there something similar in Blender?

Comment: Or you could hook verts with [Hook modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a normal lattice deform modifier but specify a vertex group that has only those faces.

[image: modifier]

Select the faces and add them to a vertex group:

[image: vertex group]

select both objects with the lattice active and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> ,Lattice deform.

[image: parent]

select the object and select the vertex group in the modifier.

[image: modifier]

Now you can only edit those faces.

[image: Object]

Comment: Indeed you can use ALL deforming modifiers selectively with vertex group. And for quicker effects you can use proportional edit with appropriate curve and radius in edit mode.

When you make a vertex group, remember to press "Assign" as well, you can easily miss it assuming its enough to create a vertex group with a selection.